# Rails form submit problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit

I've get a little problem.

My controller:

```
def new
@company = Company.new
@title = "Create company"
end

def create
@company = Company.new(params[:company])
@company.admin_id = current_user.id
if @company.save
  flash[:success] = "Company created!"
  redirect_to admin_path
else
  @title = "New company"
  render 'new'
end    
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= debug params[:company] %>

<% form_for @company, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Submit company!" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Company.rb model

```
 validates :name,
:presence => true,
:length => { :maximum => 20 }

 validates_attachment_presence :logo
```

But after submitting form I've get anyway only one error:

Name can't be blank

Of course I'm filling name and logo fields.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include your `_fields` partial, and that's probably where your problem is.
Make sure your `inputs` have appropriate `name` attributes.

Try to instantiate your model in console and see if validations really work.
You can try something like this: `c = Company.new; c.valid?; c.errors` and you'll see your errors hash in console.

Comment: Oh, sorry I've missed it:
<%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 - another fields, have the same correct values, and in the console everything works fine.

Comment: ruby-1.9.2-p0 > s.errors
 => {:name=>["can't be blank"], :logo_file_name=>["must be set."]}